# What is a word for made-more-exacting?

Tags: single-word-requests

I improved a software test by adding additional checks.

> I made the test more thorough, rigorous, and exacting; I ____ it.

What word fits the blank, meaning made-more-exacting?

Comment: Does ***it*** refer to the testing process, or to the software which you are testing? You might say that you *intensified* the requirements, but a perfect product is still perfect regardless of good testing, great testing, or no testing.

Comment: @Davo *it* refers to the test (question edited to clarify this). *intensified* I think is a good start. In a thesaurus search for that I also see *enhanced*.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, you could be said to have [refined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refine) the test, in that you have made it more exacting.

There is the (apparently obsolete) word [specificate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specificate) which may fit the meaning, but not the context, as I haven't found use of it in such a manner as you seek, i.e. 'I specificated it'

Answer (score 2):

Consider: *I **tightened** it.*

> *‘councillors have asked supermarkets to **tighten** up car park security’*
>   increase, make stricter, make more rigorous, make more stringent, make more rigid, stiffen, toughen, toughen up, heighten, escalate, scale up
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/tighten)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your best option here is fortified